# Show that $S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Let $C$ be any class of subsets of a set $X$. Let $Y \subset X$. Let $A(C)$ be the algebra generated by $C$. Let $S:=\{E \cup(B \cap Y^{c})\mid E \in S(C \cap Y)$, $B \in S(C)$}. Show that $S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, where $S(C)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $C$.

I am stuck at checking closure under complements. When I took $A \in S$ then $A=E \cup(B \cap Y^c)$, for some $E \in S(C \cap Y) $ and $B \in S(C)$. I believe that $A^c(\operatorname{in} $X$)=E^c(\operatorname{in} Y)\cup(B^c\cap Y^c)$.

But I am unable to show it analytically

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: I corrected the spelling of "complement".  The words "complement" and "compliment" are two different words that mean two different things.